# Pm2 consuming more memory

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I have deployed my `node` Application into 4 core machine using `pm2`. My Application utilizing all the 4 cores. The problem is out of 4 cores, 1 of the core eating lot of memory and other cores memory utilization was fine.

This is the command, I have used to run my application

```
 NODE_ENV="production" pm2 start bin/www -f --name="MApp" -i max
```

I am using following version

```
pm2 version = 0.6.8
node version = 0.10.22
```

May be, whatever versions I am using, they might not stable. At least can anyone suggest me which versions are stable.

Answer (score 0):

update pm2 with new version

`npm install Unitech/pm2#development -g`

```
pm2 update
```

They have resolved memory issue in their updated version.